# How to Report Closed Won Opportunities by Lead Source

Tags: reporting, opportunity, leads

This may be a rookie question but I can't figure out how to report number of closed won opportunities by lead source.

I can see the Leads By Source prebuilt report but it doesn't link to Opportunities.

I can make an Opportunity Report and filter by Lead Source by we have 14 lead sources and I don't want to make and update 14 different reports.

[image]

I feel like I am missing something simple here, but I have Googled, read docs, can't quite figure it out.

I want to see a report that has number of Closed Won Opportunities (and % closed won) by Lead Source.

Something like this.

[image]

Comment: you might also ask on the Salesforce Success forum - more sysads but basically you do this with a Matrix report on Opportunities

Answer (score 2):

So you can do this with a Standard Opportunities Report.  Change it to a matrix report, and group the rows by Lead Source, and the columns by the Won field.

[image]

The you need to create a formula field to capture the % won.  See how that formula is set up below

[image]

Then you run the report and you will now see the number of won opps by Lead source as well as the percentage of won

[image]